# How to install JServer on Free Oracle Cloud

Tags: java, oracle, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

When creating a java module ("create or replace and compile java source named ... as") in Oracle ATP, error ORA-29538 is issued. Can I install JServer in Oracle ATP DB?

Answer (score 3):

Running Java code in the database is not available for an Autonomous Database. See the list of restricted and unavailable database features for [ATP](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/atp-cloud/atpug/experienced-database-users.html#GUID-B6FB5EFC-4828-43F4-BA63-72DA74FFDB87) and [ADW](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/experienced-database-users.html#GUID-B6FB5EFC-4828-43F4-BA63-72DA74FFDB87).